# Rearranging a Regression equation

Tags: r, regression, clustered-standard-errors

I have what is probably a simple regression question but I thought I should ask since I don't have anywhere to verify it. I have an equation similar to as follows:

$x_t = x_{t-1} + \alpha.Price_t$

Now, I want to perform a regression and double cluster standard errors, but I only care about finding out the significance of $\alpha$ in my model. However, when I run a regression and double cluster then it finds the significance of every variable in the equation (and I don't know enough about regression, clustering standard errors etc. to know for sure whether or not this changes anything), so I was wondering if it is okay for me to rearrange the regression equation such that I now have a regression equation as follows:

$y_t = \alpha$ where $y_t = \frac{x_t - x_{t-1}}{Price_{t}}$

Basically, rather than having $x_t$, $x_{t-1}$ and $Price_t$ in the regression equation I want to create a new variable. For example, if at time $t$ I have $x_t = 20$, $x_{t-1} = 5$, $Price = 3$, then $y_t = \frac{20-5}{3} = 5$ which I now use in my equation $y_t = \alpha$ instead of using $x_{t} = ...$

Is this okay for me to do? Do the same rules for equations apply for regression equations when trying to find significance of variables? I've spent a lot of time trying to work things out and I'm wondering if my solution is as trivial as this.

EDIT: Here are the results depending on how I modify my equation:

$x_t = x_{t-1} + \alpha.Price_t$ :

```
t test of coefficients:

                                Estimate             Std. Error  t value  
Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)        0.0000006970812503369  0.0000006764632337684  1.03048 0.3027854   
x_t-1             -0.0000000013293857891  0.0000000014916620489 -0.89121 0.3728161   
alpha              0.0000036043929839937  0.0000151490535333780  0.23793 0.8119365   
Price             -0.0000000002237127830  0.0000000000748630484 -2.98829 0.0028055 **
alpha:Price        0.0000005547121317987  0.0000025347030495303  0.21885 0.8267693
```

$y_t = \alpha$:

```
t test of coefficients:

                   Estimate          Std. Error     t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.00000508163181759 0.00000561336549570     0.90527              0.36532    
alpha       0.00031832476448267 0.00000000705546771 45117.45748 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
```

I'm doing this in $R$ software using `coeftest` function while also double clustering for standard errors if that changes things.

I suppose my question is this: if I only care about obtaining the significance of $\alpha$, is it okay for me to rewrite my original regression equation so that I have $y_t = \alpha$ instead?

Comment: A strong clue is afforded by writing out the *complete* model: don't forget to include the error terms!

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on that a little bit? Do you mean include error terms in the regression equation? If so I'm not too sure how to interpret that...

Comment: Since $x_t = x_{t-1} + \alpha\text{Price}_t + \varepsilon_t,$  $$y_t = \frac{x_t-x_{t-1}}{\text{Price}_t}=\frac{x_t-x_{t-1}}{\text{Price}_t}=\alpha+\frac{\varepsilon_t}{\text{Price}_t}.$$ This shows that the *variance* of the error term changes with price--it's a heteroscedastic model now--and it gets really bad if there's any uncertainty in $\text{Price}_t,$ because you have to include an error term in it, too, giving the model $$y_t =\alpha+\frac{\varepsilon_t}{\text{Price}_t+\delta_t}$$ with random terms in the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: So basically the term $\frac{\epsilon_t}{Price_t}$ is the reason why there's such a huge change between the first model and second model results for $\alpha$ then? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't say, not having the data: but certainly it will contribute to some difference between the two estimates.

Answer (score -1):

No need to re-arrange anything. By default, most regression software will report the significance of the estimated coefficients one-by-one, i.e., the indicated significance  is marginal significance (= what I think you want) not joint significance as you seem to assume.

You can just ignore the output for the coefficients that are not the coefficient you are interested in.

Comment: Perhaps it's just an issue with $R$ software or something then, since my values are different depending on how I modify my equation, I've updated my original post with my results from both methods

Comment: It's nothing to do with R. The reason for the difference is in whuber's comment